# Error: Could not find or load main class xxx Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am very new to linux environment.

I am trying to run an simple hello world java class in linux environment.

## Hello .java

```
 package com.util;

    public class Hello {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("hi");

        }

    }
```

I have compiled java class in windows environment and uploaded the .class file to linux system into /home/scripts path.

my command is as follows,

```
java -cp /home/scripts com.util.Hello
```

when i am executing this command from this same /home/scripts where Hello.class is there i am getting,

Error: Could not find or load main class com.util.Hello and not able to proceed further.

can some one help me in this issue?

Comment: is "my class" is a java file or a class file ?

Comment: Did you compile it first? (`javac`)

Comment: i have compiled it in windows environment and uploaded the class file to linux system and com.util.Hello is .class file

Comment: Where exactly is your `hello.class` file? Give it entire file path please, and edit your question to improve it...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

navigate to /home/scripts using terminal

```
javac com/util/Hello.java
```

then

```
cd /home/scripts
java -cp . com.util.Hello
```

Or,

```
java -cp "/home/scripts" com.util.Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue on windows, and I solved it by adding path "." to both CLASSPATH and PATH, maybe you can try this on Linux as well.

Answer (score 2):

At first you must generate your .class file :

javac ./hello.java

This command has generated hello.class file
And after you can run your class file ! :)

java hello

Answer (score 2):

We first know javac command work well.

I also met this error,and i have resolved this.Let me share this.

First we need to find the parent path of your package in your java codes.

Then cd to that path using java package + fileName should work well at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.class` file should not reside in `/home/scripts/`, but in `/home/scripts/com/util/`. Take a look at [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#Understanding) that explains the relation between classpath, packages and directories.

Comment: i have copied class file into /home/scripts/com/util/ path and i tried this java -cp /home/scripts com.util.Hello but still same error is observed

Answer (score 0):

Before Specifying the path,ensure you follow these three things meticulously,
1. **Close the *command prompt window*, before specifying the path.
2. When *adding path, add bin and semi- colon at the end*  and
3. If JAVAC command has worked properly, try java -cp class name.**

Answer (score -1):

if you want to run program in current working directory where your class reside.

java gives three options.

first option

java -cp Tester

Second option for current working directory

java -cp . Tester

Third option export CLASSPATH variable

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:. (this is the best one if your directory changes) or

export CLASSPATH=$PWD

or

export CLASSPATH=

after that you must sorce the bashrc or bashprofile.